# Visual Studio 2010 crashes opening .cshtml files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am unable to open any CSHTML files in any ASP.NET MVC solution as VS2010 consistently crashes.

I am running Visual Studio 2010 Premium on Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1. Repairing the installation doesn't fix the issue. Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Anything in the Windows Event Log?

Comment: Do you have VS2010 SP1 installed? I had a few issues working with cshtml files before applying the patch.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command from the command line helped me resolve my issue with VS crashing on opening .cshtml files:

`devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs`

[The /ResetSkipPkgs switch is documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241276%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and has helped several other people resolve all kinds of problems with VS.